# New Order statuses in the mass action update menu in Orders / Sales?

Tags: magento-1.9, massaction

I am using Mangeto 1.9. I want to display in this menu: URL of the page:

`www.yourmagento.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index` -

This is the orders view page, where you can see all your orders.

[image]

In this menu I want to **display all custom created Order Statuses**.
Here is a screenshot from my Order Statuses page:

[image]

I found that all statuses are displayed in the Order View page under the **History tab** . Take a look:
[image]

I found the file which is answering for the mass "Actions" menu and adding options in there.

Its' located here:

```
/public_html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

That's the code for 3 options in select menu:

```
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
    ));
```

I am showing you the code for only 3 of them, I think there is no need to show all and make this post more largest then needed.
From this code I understand that I have to write code for every custom order state.

**My first question is**: Is it possible to display all newly created order statuses automatically in this menu like it's happen in the menu of Order View page in the history tab.

I found the code which is answering for the options in the order view page in the history tab and there it is:

`/public_html/beta/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml`

and here is the code in this file which is calling the options:

```
        <select name="history[status]" class="select" id="history_status">
        <?php foreach (Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_code ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getOrder()->getStatus()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

With this code all custom created Order statuses are displayed automatically in this page.

**My second question is** how I can make the same thing but for the mass Action select menu in the Orders / Sales page ? Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance!